# main.css file not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Introduction**

I have two domains, http://mauricevandorst.com/ and http://tacticalmotion.nl/.

---

**What do I want**

I want the website [https://mauricevandorst.com/personal-page/index.html](http://www.mauricevandorst.com/personal-page/index.html) to be the same website as [http://tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/index.html](http://www.tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/index.html). The files and paths are exactly the same, so it should work but unfortunately it does not..

---

**The issue**

On my domain, [mauricevandorst](http://www.mauricevandorst.com/personal-page/index.html), the .css files load perfectly. 
On my other domain, [tacticalmotion](http://www.tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/index.html), the .css files do not load at all.

To load the .css files in my Index.html I use the following code:

```
<!-- Custom Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The CSS files I use can be found here:

[main.css](http://www.tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/css/main.css)  -  [bootstrap.css](http://www.tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/css/bootstrap.css)  -  [bootstrap.min.css](http://www.tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/css/bootstrap.min.css)

---

**Extra information**

I have found out that when loading http://www.mauricevandorst.com/personal-page/index.html (http instead of https) gives the mistake too. Could it possibly be an SSL certificate that misses?

Comment: Looks like it's working correct https://www.tacticalmotion.nl/personal-page/css/main.css clear your cache and try again.

Comment: You need to replace this `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css`, by `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css` or `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css`

Comment: Your main.css is loading correctly but bootstrap.min.css does not load because it comes from `http://` and not `https://`. You can use `//` if you want to use current protocol

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, since your website is in HTTPS you can't load HTTP content.

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

The best shot you've got is simply to use https CDN especially for bootstrap
Juste have a shot with thoose url.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```